# Convert from wrong unix time stamp to correct

Tags: date, datetime, unix, momentjs

I've inherited a problem. A front end calendar application that I have to update is treating every event as being in unix time. No matter what timezone the calendar is meant to be displayed in.

Our DB saves every event as unix time.

The calendar will assume that if I create an event at 7:00 PM it is 7:00 PM UTC. How would I go about converting this from 7:00 PM UTC to 7:00 PM [selected timezone] so that when it gets to the DB it'll be saved in the proper unix time stamp.

Tools available: Moment (with timezone), jquery.

Comment: FYI... UTC is not "unix time". All you should have to do is figure out what the correct offset needed to convert "[selected timezone]" to UTC and add/subtract that. Or alternatively maybe store "7:00 PM [selected timezone]" instead of just "7:00 PM", but that's going to depend on what database you're talking about...

Comment: @twalberg - add/subtract should usually be avoided.  Most often there are better approaches, such as the second one you suggested.  However, the OP showed no code, so we can only speculate...